# set command in windows not working for django SECRET_KEY | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable

Tags: python, django, windows

I set the SECRET_KEY with set command in the terminal, but nothing works

> **set SECRET_KEY='9l=jjp#g0-mbdfsntqww91s9b^a!kj44ljl4f5h!+uoft'**

**settings.py:**

```py
from pathlib import Path
import environ

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

env = environ.Env(
DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=False)
if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    environ.Env.read_env()

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

**.env:**

```
SECRET_KEY='9l=jjp#g0-mbdfsntqww91s9b^a!kj44ljl4f5h!+uoft'
DEBUG=True
```

So as you can read, the READ_DOT_ENV_FILE should be True to let django read the system variables from .env file, otherwise, it'll read the variables from the terminal (session) by defining them in it using the *set* command.

In this case:

**set DEBUG=True**

**set SECRET_KEY='9l=jjp#g0-mbdfsntqww91s9b^a!kj44ljl4f5h!+uoft'**

Comment: What is the error you get? Did you echo SECRET_KEY to see whether it's set properly ? What about DEBUG?

Comment: DEBUG worked, but SECRET_KEY didnt
That's the error : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable

Comment: If you are in Power shell, use $env:VAR_NAME="VALUE". And to verify the same, give $env:VAR_NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.
I found the solution.
Instead of using **set**, you have to use:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('value','key')
```

I tried that and It works with setting the SECRET_KEY & DEBUG variables.

Closed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue and I used
$env:DEBUG="True".
$env:SECRET_KEY="paste_your_secret_key_here".

It's surely gonna work